# Maximum number of remembered connections of Wifi Direct in Android

Tags: android, connection, wifi-direct

I'm doing my research in Wifi Direct and trying to develop an android app for real experiments, so that, I want the device to remember as many connections as possible in order to click only once (the first time) the annoying accept button so, here is a simple question that I didn't manage to answer:

I would like to know if there is a maximun number of remembered connections/groups of Wifi Direct in Android?

I've read somewhere that it could be up to 31 but nothing official, and that doesn't work for me, I would like to remember around 100. Does it depends on each device? If anyone knows where I can find the specifications of wifi direct for android devices it would very helpful, if it exists...and also any own experiences about this topic is welcome.

Comment: Here are some Android Wi-Fi Direct resources: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wi-fi-direct/uWpuOzHY6y0

Comment: Thank you Brendan, that's a very nice compilation!